# Ember-data async models in templates

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Hi I have an async model in Ember (because fixtures force you to use async:true) which is not working in the template (the promise is probably not resolved).

This code for example:

```
{{#each tag in imagepost.tags}}
    <strong class="links-no-color"><a>{{tag}}</a></strong>
{{/each}}
```

produce:

```
<App.Tag:ember625:1> <App.Tag:ember626:2> <App.Tag:ember627:3>
```

Doesn't Ember suppose to see that i access the tags and make the request to the tags endpoint?
How can i manually tell him to work it out? this won't work(in a component):

```
comments: function() {
    this.get('imagepost.comments').then(function(val){ return val;});
}.property('imagepost'),
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question in the second half, it definitely won't work for a few reasons, one, you don't return anything to the computed property, two, the computed property would just be a promise, not the resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's working!  But you need to reference whatever property you have on the tag model, instead of just the tag record in the loop (I did tag.name)

```
{{#each tag in imagepost.tags}}
    <strong class="links-no-color"><a>{{tag.name}}</a></strong>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Oh you are right i forgot it is now a model by itself, thanks